# Full height Background Image with centered width

Tags: html, css, background-image

I have an 4:3 aspect ratio image to put as a background-image.
My first aim is to have a full height image, resizing accordingly to the height, with variable width (depending on the height). The image should be centered.
For example, if I have a 16:9 viewport it should display the background-image centered with left and right blank spaces.

I tried different method (using as example 4:3 image with 16:9 viewport).
First of all, `background-size` both with `contain` and with `cover` applied to the `<body>` tag:

- with `cover` it respects the aspect ratio but crop the image at the top and at the bottom
- with `contain` it doesn't cover the whole viewport, but actually only the `body`

Also using `background-size: auto 100%;` produce the same effect as `contain`

This is the CSS code I used:

```
 body#home {
  background-image: url(../bg.jpg);
  background-size: auto 100%;
  -moz-background-size: auto 100%;
  -webkit-background-size: auto 100%;
  -o-background-size: auto 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
 }
```

Comment: Doesn't your `<body>` cover the entire viewport?

Comment: try `contain` and add `body, html {min-height:100%;}`

Comment: With the suggestion of @Pete it actually works :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Pete, with this code it actually works:

```
html, body {
  min-height: 100%;
}
body#home {
  background-image: url(../ppersia-home.jpg);
  background-size: contain;
  -moz-background-size: contain;
  -webkit-background-size: contain;
  -o-background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
 }
```

Now I've just to add some other background pattern to avoid monochrome color in the left and right blank spaces

Answer (score 0):

Update your css:

```
background-position: center center; /* needs horizontal and vertical positions */
background-size: contain; /* use contain so your image fits inside */
```